# convert string to array with int and None

Tags: python, string, lambda, nonetype

I was trying this code:

```
data=str([1, 2, 3, None, None, 4, 5])
temp=data.strip('][').split(', ')
array=list(map(lambda x: None if x==None else int(x), temp))
print(array)
```

However I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

How can I get this to put the array back into an array? Thanks

Comment: Use `x == 'None'`

Comment: thanks @abdusco that worked. Just had a mental block why it wasn't working I guess

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(x)` would avoid the need for any condition.

Comment: @abdusco I have an interview coming up and I was practicing leetcode with this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/serialize-and-deserialize-binary-tree/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather converting the list to a Python-specific string representation, use a standard (or at least commonly used) encoding like JSON.

```
lst = [1,2,3, None, None, 4, 5]
data = json.dumps(lst)
assert lst == json.loads(data)
```